# Разделить слова строки в алфавитном порядке по vector<set<string>> C++

Tags: c++, строки, vector, stl, множества

Задание такое: есть строка, в которой слова разделены пробелами, и нужно запихнуть их в вектор из множеств, каждое из которых включает все слова, начинающиеся на одну и ту же букву. Я не могу определить способ такого разделения.

С дроблением строки я разобрался.

```
void parse_string(const string &src, vector <set <string> > &result) {
    string word;
    stringstream wordStream(srcString);

    while (getline(wordStream, word, ' ')) {
        //result[int(word.front())].push_back(word);
    }
}
```

Я так понимаю, по индексу что-либо вставлять ничего не удастся. А создавать для каждого набора слов по сету будет тоже муторно. Как тут быть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, а почему не по индексу? создаем заранее

```
vector<set<string>> v(256);
```

А потом - если есть `string word` - то записываем

```
v[word[0]].insert(word);
```

Примерно так...

**Update**

Чтоб экономить - добавлять придется тяжко - типа такого (считайте, что это псевдокод - я не компилирую, просто показываю идею):

```
auto it = find_if(v.begin(),v.end(),[word](auto& s){ return (*s.begin() == word); }
if (it != v.end()) it->insert(word);
else v.push_back(set<string>(word));
```

Стоит ли оно того? накладные расходы ведь невелики...

Comment: Хорошо, а можно ли сэкономить место в векторе? Или это самый экономный вариант?

Comment: А если там гарантированно только буквы, то можно на 57 элементов выделить, от `char(65)` до `char(122)` и каждый раз при выборе индекса отнимать 65

Comment: Моя задача ограничена строго stl, но всё же спасибо за помощь!

Comment: А у вас должен быть именно `vector<set<string>>`? тогда просто удобнее держать сразу для 256 символов - иначе вам придется держать еще таблицу соответствия букв индексам. А вот если можно `map<char,set<string>>` - то это решило бы все проблемы.

Comment: Именно вектор. Кстати говоря, 256 это размер таблицы аски? Ибо я мог бы обойтись всего 62 (26 букв лат. алфавита + заглавные + цифры)

Comment: См. дополненный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать такой вариант, он, конечно, занимает больше времени, но зато на выходе меньше памяти.

```
void parse_string(vector <set <string> > &result) {
    map<char, vector<string>> temp;
    string word;
    while(cin >> word){
        temp[word[0]].push_back(word);
    }
    for(auto p : temp){
        set<string> t;
        for(auto w : p.second){
            t.insert(w);
        }
        result.push_back(t);
    }
}
```

https://ideone.com/tATBEF